# Let $a(z),b(z)$ be two non-zero complex polynomials such that....

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Let $a(z),b(z)$ be two non-zero complex polynomials. Then $a(z)\overline{b(z)}$ is analytic iff
>
> 1. $a(z)$ is constant
> 2. $a(z)b(z)$ is constant
> 3. $\overline{a(z)}b(z)$  is constant
> 4. $b(z)$ is constant

I am not sure how to tackle it. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try showing that if $f$ is analytic and nonconstant, then $\overline f$ is not analytic.

Comment: I think $a(z)$ is constant?